# Getting Error magento product upload using dataflow profile import process

Tags: magento-1.9, import, dataflow

I am uploading products using dataflow profile import process.

but it is not working and I am getting errors.

screenshot : [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you using any field with name of 'Analog' in CSV

Comment: Importing products using dataflow in Magento, can go wrong in many, many ways. You really have to elaborate on what you are trying to do and what is going wrong (i.e. what the errors are). In the way you are asking this question, your question should be marked as not being a real question.

Comment: I think you are passing analong in type column type contain magento product type no other values supported.

Comment: best solution is to use magmi

Comment: problem solved using magmi!!Thank you @BabyinMagento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Default import/export , you can use popular 3rd party tool called "MAgmi" , you will get all information here : http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, you have a dropdown attribute named `type` and you are trying to add a product which has value `Analog` for that column. If so, you need to make sure that the attribute `type` has the option `Analog` in the backend.

While importing products, you will need to add all the options before the import. Only then, the import will proceed for that row otherwise that row will be skipped.